# What does C# "await" actually return?

Tags: c#, async-await

Below is some code that runs "as is" in LinqPad. It demonstrates my misunderstanding of what `await` is doing. See further down for results and my issue.

```
    void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    StartIt(cts.Token);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    "Cancelling".Dump();
    cts.Cancel();
}


// Define other methods and classes here
async Task StartIt(CancellationToken token)
{
    "StartIt".Dump();
    var o = new TestClass();

    await o.Step0(token);

}

public class TestClass
{
    public async Task Step0(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var t = Step1(token);
        ("Step0.Task.Id => " + t.Id).Dump();        

        await t;
        ("Step0.IsCancelled? " + t.IsCanceled).Dump();
    }

    public async Task Step1(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var t = Step2(token);
        ("Step1.Task.Id => " + t.Id).Dump();

        try {
            await t;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            "Step1.OperationCanceledException".Dump();
        }
        ("Step1.IsCancelled? " + t.IsCanceled).Dump();
    }

    public Task Step2(CancellationToken token)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>{
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                "Done".Dump();
            }, token);
    }
}
```

So the above produces:

```
StartIt
Step1.Task.Id => 17
Step0.Task.Id => 18
Cancelling
Step1.OperationCanceledException
Step1.IsCancelled? True
Step0.IsCancelled? False
```

My issues:

I expect Step0's and Step1's task.Id to be the same.
(therefore) I expect the cancellation that occurs to propagate up the methods so that I can interrogate `t.IsCanceled` and take appropriate action.

But I'm getting a different `Task` being returned to `Step0`. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you read my [introduction to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). Also, there's an excellent tutorial built-in to LinqPad (Samples -> Download/import more samples -> Asynchrony in C# 5 Interactive Tutorial).

Task identifiers in `async` code can be a bit tricky. What happens is that every `async Task` method creates its own task that represents that method invocation. So, `Task.Run` creates a `Task` and returns it to `Step2` and `Step1` (id `17` in your test). `Step1` also creates a `Task` and returns it to `Step0` (id `18` in your test). `Step0` also creates a `Task` and returns it to `StartIt`, and `StartIt` also creates a `Task` and returns it to `Main`.

So, the `Task` returned by `Task.Run` (which is the same `Task` returned by `Step2`) is cancelled. `Step1` catches the cancelled exception, so it returns normally, and the `Task` returned by `Step1` is not cancelled.

If you want to propagate exceptions, don't catch the cancelled exception (or if you do want to catch it to log, then re-throw it via `throw;`).

Comment: Thanks for your time Stephen. This behaviour seems odd to me. I would have thought cancellation of an async task, especially from desktop apps where there is often a Cancel button for just such events, is expected behaviour not exceptional. The fact that there are Task.IsCanceled, .IsFaulted etc properties seems to indicate that task status should flow up the task's "stack". Just seems ugly to have to have all the methods on the stack to have to have try/catch code to handle this.

Comment: ...Presumably if the task succeeds all the Tasks up the stack get a Task.Status == RanToCompletion? If so why not the same with Cancelled?

Comment: You don't need `try`/`catch`, because `await` will propagate exceptions. So if you take out all your `try` blocks, then you'll see faults and cancellation propagate up naturally.

Comment: If I don't have `try/catch` around each of the awaits then each method does not get to handle the cancellation event and act accordingly. The exception (as you say) is propagated all the way up. My gripe is that I have to handle an expected situation with exception handling rather than using `task.IsCanceled`.